# Zend Framework: why does whitespace validate against my regular expression?

Tags: regex, zend-framework, validation, zend-form

I have the following code:

```
$sfKeyword = new Zend_Form_SubForm();

$tfKeyword = $sfKeywords->createElement('text', 'keyword');
$tfKeyword->setLabel('Keyword: ');
$tfKeyword->addValidator('regex', false, array('/[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*/'));
```

This regex validates keywords and is supposed to allow only a-z, A-Z, and _ as the first characters and then additionally allowing digits 0-9, zero or more occurrences.

But when entering some string with whitespace in between, the string passes the validator without error message. This shouldn't be the case.

Note, I've also tried

```
'/[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*/s'
```

but there's no difference (as expected).

What's wrong with the regex (or Zend Framework)?

Comment: However I needed to correct my expression to allow white space.The question itself helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your regex is not anchored.  That means that as long as some part of the string matches the regex, the regex will match.  Instead, anchor it:

```
/^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*$/
```

The leading `^` character says "The start of the string", and the trailing `$` means "The end of the string".  So now it will match any string that starts with `[a-zA-Z_]` and then is followed by one or more `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` until the end of the string.